# tiny mce shows � in html output when i press enter in editor

Tags: unicode, tinymce

When i use enter for new line or paste from other file or somewhere else it gives me � in html output
my tiny mce init is as follows

```
tinymce.init({
     selector:'textarea',
     convert_urls: true,
     entity_encoding : "raw",
     plugins: "image contextmenu link",
     image_advtab: true,
     autosave_interval: "20s",
     paste_word_valid_elements: "b,strong,i,em,h1,h2",
     paste_data_images: true,
     paste_as_text: true,
     spellchecker_wordchar_pattern: /[^\s,\.]+/g,
     contextmenu: "link image inserttable | cell row column deletetable",
     rel_list: [
    {title: 'Lightbox', value: 'lightbox'},
    {title: 'Table of contents', value: 'toc'}
],
table_clone_elements: "strong em a"         });
```

a screenshot of output is added
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Nothing to do with Tiny MCE. You are copy-and-pasting text that includes bytes that are not valid UTF-8 characters. Often this is the result of copy-pasting Word or Outlook text with "Smart Quotes" (a nonstandard remap of typographically pleasing punctuation to a reserved control byte area). Some of yours appear to be opening and closing quotation marks, while others may be "non-breaking spaces". Yet others could be embedded word processor control codes.

If you copy and paste **directly** from Word/Outlook into a UTF-8 display web page, often the browser will know to select the UTF-8 version of the clipboard, and bring in valid UTF-8 characters for the Smart Quotes. However, this behavior is not guaranteed.

Comment: but i have typed and pressed enter for new line and then it shows also same thing.

Comment: Where did this text come from? Was it copy-pasted from some other document, either on a PC or on another Web page? Is there any other processing going on, other than Tiny MCE? It sure looks in your example like each sentence is followed by something *other* than a normal space and then a normal space, and quotation marks have been marked as invalid (probably Smart Quotes originally). The centered dividers are probably a Smart Quotes en-dash or em-dash, invalid in UTF-8.

Comment: If this is happening on something you actually *typed* in, my guess would be that your Tiny MCE is incorrectly configured for Windows-1252 encoding rather than UTF-8. You'd have to read the documentation carefully. I have no idea why a simple "Enter" would produce an "invalid character", unless there's something very odd in the Tiny MCE configuration.

Comment: yeah i am new @ tiny mce i have mentioned my init function for tiny mce. i have pressed simply enter and it shows same invalid character

Comment: Try changing `entity_encoding : "raw",` to `entity_encoding : "named",`. I suspect that it's sticking binary characters in (Latin-1 encoding) instead of `&nbsp;` etc.